# Radio button onClick when javascript is disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Morning,
Im just wondering, is there a way to make the radio button do something onclick when javascript on that browser is disabled?
i currently have this code that works when javascript is on only.

```
$links.="<tr>
<td style='width:10%;vertical-align:top;' class='space'>
<a href='".$href_link."'>
<input id='radio_".$value[0]."' type='radio' name='single' onclick='alert(\"hello\")' />
</a>
</td>
<td style='width:90%;vertical-align:middle;' class='space'>
<a href='".$href_link."'>".$value[0]."</a>
</td>
</tr>";
```

and this is the redirect function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function redirect(loc)
{
    window.location = loc;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to year 2014. Who have javascript disabled?

Comment: NO! you can't do anything, if javascript is disabled in the client system.

Comment: thanx everyone, @Hardy i have a radio button and i need it to send the user to a new page when its clicked on. that needs to work for when js is on and off. I tried to wrap an anchor tag around the radio button but it still doesnt work :( any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can only use `<noscript></noscript>` like: `<noscript>Enable Javascript to view page properly!</noscript>` to display a message to the front end user, that they need to enable javascript to view this page properly, and hide the content on the page using CSS, since `<noscript>` can be used in `head` and `body`.

See more info here: [The noscript tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp)

Answer (score 1):

javscript code work when its enable there is no way to work js code without javascript enable

But you can handle this case

Make a **div** in your html and set like below

```
<div id="enablejs" >please enable your javacsript</div>
```

and on load call this js script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 /* if js enable then it remove on document 
    load and rest of work run as previous
    other wise a div show with message
    that enable your Javascript */
$("#enablejs").remove();

});
```